# Making XRANDR settings permanent

Tags: x11, gnome, xrandr, resolution

GNOME 3
Gnomebuntu - 15.10

I have an Intel NUC i3 6th gen and a 4k monitor with 32GB of ram. If I type the command xrandr after doing

```
"xrandr -s 4096x2160"

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4096 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 4096x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   4096x2160     24.00*   23.98  
   3840x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1152x864      59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I want to make this change permanent so I did the following -

create .xprofile with touch xprofile

run -

```
cvt 4096 2160 60

# 4096x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 760.00 MHz
Modeline "4096x2160_60.00"  760.00  4096 4432 4880 5664  2160 2163 2173 2237 -hsync +vsync
```

I then added the following to my .xprofile

```
xrandr --newmode "4096x2160_60.00"  760.00  4096 4432 4880 5664  2160 2163 2173 2237 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA1 "4096x2160_60.00"

xrandr -s "4096x2160_60.00"
```

If I log out and log back in, I am kicked back out to the login screen. I then have to drop to terminal, delete .xprofile, and then return to the GUI. What am I doing wrong here? I can do the above commands by hand and it works fine. My current resolution after doing this by hand is 4096x2160. My monitor is incorrectly identified. It is a 50inch and not a 70inch. Am I missing something simple?

[image: My current resolution.]

Comment: commands look good, could be a problem with incompatible hardware. What is in .xprofile ? post or pastebin the contents. To make xrandr changes stay , run a script at login or edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf - http://askubuntu.com/questions/186288/how-to-detect-and-configure-an-output-with-xrandr